# Dropdownlist validate against text field using OnServerValidate in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have Country Dropdownlist with value eg: "US and NON US" and a text field name "State"

when the user enter State of US for eg "MN" in text field and select US from drop down  I need to validate the state  entered in textfield with the state values of US from the Database table

There is a table which contains only states of "US"

Also when the user select "Non US" from drop down and when the button click I need to validate the state  for NON US since there is no state values for "Non US" from the Database table and show Message like "only US is valid"
 I tried the code as below but dont know how to get the State value in the Function. what code I need add to work on this. I am new to ASP.NET. Thanks in Advance for any help.

```
 Country:<asp:dropdownlist id="country_add" Runat="server" TabIndex="27">
                                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="US"> US </asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Non US"> Non US</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:dropdownlist> 
                                <asp:customvalidator id="country_Batch" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMatState" OnServerValidate="validate_State"
                                        ErrorMessage="*" text="*"></asp:customvalidator>


    <asp:textbox id="txtMatState" runat="server" TabIndex="21"></asp:textbox></li>
```

**Validation:**

```
       Sub validate_State(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e 
          As ServerValidateEventArgs)
  Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(sConn)           
            Dim cmdState As SqlCommand
            Dim dtrState As SqlDataReader              
            objConn.Open()
            e.IsValid = False
    Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM country WHERE 
[STATE] = '" & e.Value & "' "
cmdState = New SqlCommand(sSQL, objConn)
            dtrState = cmdState.ExecuteReader()
            While dtrState.Read()
                e.IsValid = True
            End While

            objConn.Close()
        End Sub
```

Comment: so you want to access the value of the dropdown-list in the validation function, is that right?

Comment: @Homungus yes correct

Comment: the validation takes place in your page code behind - so just access the controls you want, e.g. `country_add.SelectedValue` to get the currently selected value from the dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation takes place in your page code behind - so just access the controls you want, e.g. `country_add.SelectedValue` to get the currently selected value from the dropdownlist.

To add a custom error message in the validation-handler, just set the property of the CustomValidator like this:

`country_Batch.ErrorMessage = "your desired error message"`

Comment: How to set the CustomValidator ErrorMessage in the Function please help

Comment: But I want to display the Error Message in the Form how to display the Error Message Please help

Comment: @HomungusI tried the below code  ElseIf country_add.SelectedValue = "Non US" Then
              e.IsValid = False
              country_Batch.ErrorMessage = "Please select only US to submit the Form"
          End If

Comment: you could use a validation summary control for this - but your questions are getting more and more basic, so please start your own research e.g. here for the validation summary: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary?view=netframework-4.8